# CW decomposition of topo space

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

we know that $S^n = e^0 \sqcup e^n.$ Then CW decomposition of $S^n$ the following $$S^n = \bigcup\limits_{i = 0}^nX^{(n)}, X^{(0)}\subseteq X^{(1)} \subseteq \ldots \subseteq X^{(n)},$$ where $X^{(0)} = e^0, X^{(n)} = e^n, X^{(1)},\ldots, X^{(n-1)} \mbox{ are empty}.$

My question is CW decomposition of $S^n$ above right or wrong??

I think that replace $X^{(n)} = e^n$ by $X^{(n)} = S^n$??

Can you explain for me? Thankyou very much!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is $X^{(n)}$? The $n$-skeleton? You write $X^{(i)} \subseteq X^{(i+1)}$, but then how $X^{(0)}$ can be nonempty and $X^{(1)}$ be empty, as you say?

Comment: Your equation $X^{(n)}=e^n$ is wrong; what is true is that $X^{(n)} = \overline e^n$ (the closure of $e^n$). Your statements that $X^{(1)},...,X^{(n-1)}$ are empty are also wrong; what is true is that $X^{(0)}=X^{(1)}=...=X^{(n-1)}$. I suggest careful reading of a textbook chapter on CW complexes, such as in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" book.

Answer (score 0):

If $X^{(1)}$ has $X^{(0)}\not=\emptyset$ as a subset, it can't be empty... In fact, the $(n-1)$-skeleton is the same as the $0$-skeleton in this case, because the $k$-skeleton is the union of all cells of dimension at most $k$. By the same statement, $X^{(n)}=S^n$, because it contains all the cells of $S^n$.

Comment: @ fixedp. If $X = e^0\sqcup e^n\sqcup e^{2n}$ then how to CW decomposition of $X$ ?

Comment: Please read the second sentence I wrote.

Comment: @ fixedp. if $X = e^0\sqcup e^n\sqcup e^{2n}$ then  CW decomposition of $X$ is $$X^{(0)} = X^{(1)} = \ldots = X^{(n-1)} = e^0, X^{(n)} = e^0\sqcup e^n, X^{(n+1)} = X^{(n+2)} = \ldots = X^{(2n)} = X$$ right or wrong?

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: @ fixedp. Now if $S^n = e^0 \sqcup e^n$ then CW decomposition of $X$ is $$X^{(0)} = X^{(1)}  = \ldots  = X^{(n-1)} = e^0, X^{(n)}  = S^n$$  so $$  H_n(X^{(n)}, X^{(n-1)}) \cong \mathbb{Z},\forall n\geqslant 0$$ right or wrong??

Comment: I feel you may be better off reading (and understanding) the algebraic topology textbook of your choice instead of asking a long list of individual yes/no questions. These questions are all very closely related and can all be resolved by understanding the same basic concept.

Answer (score 0):

A really easy $CW$ decomposition of $S^n$ is given by using only an $n$-cell (say $e^n$) and a $0$-cell (say $e^0$). Consider the attaching map given by $f: \partial e^n \to e^0$ and define $X = e^n \bigsqcup_f e^o$.